# uwsgi + python import error

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I've configured my nginx server with uwsgi and python and when I also installed WebOb but when i hit the url in the broswer it gives uwsgi error Python application not found and the uwsgi application log says:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 1.0.4 (32bit) on [Thu Aug  2 11:14:31 2012] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 01 August 2012 15:37:48
current working directory: /home/paul/Desktop/project/studio713
detected binary path: /home/paul/Desktop/project/studio713/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:8807 fd 4
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 23:06:40)  [GCC 4.6.3]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x85db738
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
added ironjob/ai/ to pythonpath.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ironjob/ai/index.py", line 5, in <module>
from webob import Response
ImportError: No module named webob
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 14878, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 14882, cores: 1)
[pid: 14878|app: -1|req: -1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {38 vars in 911 bytes} [Thu Aug  2 11:14:41    2012] GET /ai?api=%3CIron%3E%3CAction%3E%3CService%3EUserAuth%3C/Service%3E%3CUsername%3Eadmin%3C/Username%3E%3CPassword%3Eadmin%3C/Password%3E%3C/Action%3E%3C/Iron%3E => generated 48 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 63 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

Thanks in advance  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this, may be this can help..
[ImportError: No module named webob](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-non-relational/ZbQyWbDqff0)